# Make isKinematic false when OnCollisionEnter()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with my script, I want to make rb.isKinematic go from true to false when collision is detected. With this script, nothing happens when a supposed collision is happening which means what rb.Kinematic = false does not work... The problem is that collision CANNOT  be detected in the first place because rb.isKinematic is initially true (in my other script)! I checked this using Debug.Log to detect collisions. How can I fix this problem?

```
string lastTagCollided = "";
public Rigidbody rb;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Pentagon" && lastTagCollided == "Pyramid")
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        transform.DetachChildren();
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("Sphere"));
    }

    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Pyramid" && lastTagCollided == "Pentagon")
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        transform.DetachChildren();
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("Sphere"));
    }

    lastTagCollided = col.gameObject.tag;
}
```

My other script if you are curious:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
    {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Pyramid" || col.gameObject.tag == "Pentagon") 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        gameObject.transform.SetParent (col.gameObject.transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your thought might be correct. It can be easily tested with a breakpoint or a debug print.

Comment: did you check that OnCollisionEnter function is called? Is your game 2D or 3D?

Comment: My project is a 3D smartphone game.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing those pieces of code to

```
string lastTagCollided = "";
public Rigidbody rb;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    Debug.Log("Debug 1: Collision " + col.gameObject.tag);
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Pentagon" && lastTagCollided == "Pyramid")
    {
    Debug.Log("Debug 2: col.gameObject.tag == \"Pentagon\" && lastTagCollided == \"Pyramid\" results true - Collision " + col.gameObject.tag);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        transform.DetachChildren();
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("Sphere"));
    }

    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Pyramid" && lastTagCollided == "Pentagon")
    {
    Debug.Log("Debug 3: col.gameObject.tag == \"Pyramid\" && lastTagCollided == \"Pentagon\" results true - Collision " + col.gameObject.tag);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        transform.DetachChildren();
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("Sphere"));
    }

    lastTagCollided = col.gameObject.tag;
}
}
```

and

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
    {
    Debug.Log("Debug 1: Collision " + col.gameObject.tag);
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Pyramid" || col.gameObject.tag == "Pentagon") 
        {
            Debug.Log("Debug 2: col.gameObject.tag == \"Pyramid\" || col.gameObject.tag == \"Pentagon\" results true - Collision " + col.gameObject.tag);
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            gameObject.transform.SetParent (col.gameObject.transform);
        }
}
```

This will give you nice logs to see if things the collisions are happening or not.

You may also want to log what rb.isKinematic is before and after and if you can't figure it out from there, edit your post with the output of your Unity Console with those logs and any more information you can provide.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My hypothesis was indeed true. The problem is that collision CANNOT be detected in the first place because rb.isKinematic is initially true (in my other script). How can I fix this though? I can't find a way...